# I get AWS ECR exit status 255 despite using AWS ubuntu containers

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-codebuild, aws-ecr

I am trying to build a docker container in AWS code build as a means to deploy a container to ECR, but I get this error.

```
Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --region ap-southeast-1). Reason: exit status 255
```

[image]

This command was run on the buildspec.yml file, using aws/codebuild/ubuntu-base:14.04 and Enable this flag if you want to build Docker images or want your builds to get elevated privileges.

The log files are as follows:

```
[Container] 2018/10/11 00:52:49 Running command $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email)

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::502776083946:assumed-role/code-build-timesheet/AWSCodeBuild-f1d205b1-b03f-4727-a4d7-a02118021eec is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: *

[Container] 2018/10/11 00:52:52 Command did not exit successfully $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email) exit status 255
[Container] 2018/10/11 00:52:52 Phase complete: INSTALL Success: false
[Container] 2018/10/11 00:52:52 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email). Reason: exit status 255
```

Comment: Even `Error while executing command: $(aws ecr get-login --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --no-include-email). Reason: exit status 255` is not working

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This status code usually indicates an unauthorized user. To fix this, we need to let our Code Build role be able to talk to `ECR`. To do this: Go to `IAM` and then attach a `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser` policy to your `CodeBuild` role.

Comment: I was getting a similar error trying to invalidate my cloudfront cache - adding an IAM permission to do this to the codebuild role fixed the problem

Answer (score 4):

The aws-cli version 2 has been updated and the command `get-login` was depreciated, you should use `get-login-password`.

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login
--username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com
```

You can see the updated documentation to build a docker image in CodeBuild: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

Is there any more specific error in your cloudwatch log? Like AccessDenied or something else? There should be some details in the log around the failed command part.
Thanks,
Xin

Comment: Updated. it says unauthorized for get authorization token

Comment: Yes, you can add the related permission to your service role, you can refer to this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added the permission but was still getting the same issue. Later found that my "**Permissions boundary**" in the IAM role was not letting the permission go through. So if you set Permission policies to allow `ecr:GetAuthorizationToken` but have Permissions boundary enabled as well then you need to add the same permission to the Permissions boundary (or remove Permissions boundary).

[image]